# Get Records from 2 patient Tables in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery

I have Two tables OPPatient AND Pharmacy

```
select SUM(Amtpaid) 
from OPPatient 
where startdate >= '2024-11-01' AND enddate  < '2024-12-01' 
select Sum(Amtpaid) 
from Pharmacy 
where startdate >= '2024-11-01' AND enddate  < '2024-12-01'
```

Need output like

| AmtPaid | AmtPaid |
| --- | --- |
| 10000 | 40000 |

Tried above query which is returning AmtPaid with 2 record like

| AmtPaid |
| --- |
| 10000 |
| 40000 |

but i need as

| AmtPaid | AmtPaid |
| --- | --- |
| 100000 | 40000 |

Comment: Please ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question. Please either ask re 1 bad query/function with obligatory [mre], including why you think it should return something else or are unsure at the 1st subexpression that it doesn't give what you expect or are stuck, justified by reference to authoritative documentation, or ask about your overall goal giving working parts you can do with justification & a [mre]. Then misunderstood code doesn't belong. But please ask about unexpected behaviour 1st because misconceptions get in the way of your goal. [ask] [Help] Basic questions are faqs.

Answer (score 2):

Just `select` both values:

```
select
    (
        select sum(amtpaid) 
        from oppatient 
        where startdate >= '2024-11-01' and enddate  < '2024-12-01' 
    ) as amtpaid_patient,
    (
        select sum(amtpaid) 
        from pharmacy 
        where startdate >= '2024-11-01' and enddate  < '2024-12-01'
    ) as amtpaid_pharmacy
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use cte   to solve the problem

```
;with  OPPatientcte as (

                        SELECT SUM(Amtpaid)  as AmtpaidOPPatient
                        FROM OPPatient 
                        WHERE 
                                     startdate >= '2024-11-01' 
                                 AND enddate  < '2024-12-01'

) 
,Pharmacycte as (

                        SELECT Sum(Amtpaid) as AmtpaidPharmacy 
                        FROM Pharmacy 
                        WHERE        startdate >= '2024-11-01' 
                                 AND enddate  < '2024-12-01'
)
SELECT *
FROM OPPatientcte,Pharmacycte
```

You can create insert Base data  with the following statements:

```
 create table OPPatient(Amtpaid int,startdate date,enddate date)
 create table Pharmacy(Amtpaid int,startdate date,enddate date)

 insert into OPPatient
 (Amtpaid,startdate,enddate)
 select 5000,'2024-11-01','2024-11-01'
 union all select 5000,'2024-11-01','2024-10-01'
  
   insert into Pharmacy
 (Amtpaid,startdate,enddate)
 select 20000,'2024-11-01','2024-11-01'
 union all select 20000,'2024-11-01','2024-12-01'
```

Answer (score -1):

This is an other way to pivot your result using the aggregate function `MAX()` with `CASE` clause :

```
select MAX(case when source = 'OPPatient' then amtpaid end) as amtpaid_OPPatient,
       MAX(case when source = 'Pharmacy' then amtpaid end) as amtpaid_Pharmacy
from (
  select SUM(Amtpaid) as amtpaid, 'OPPatient' as source
  from OPPatient 
  where startdate >= '2024-11-01' AND enddate  < '2024-12-01' 
  union all
  select Sum(Amtpaid) as amtpaid, 'Pharmacy' as source
  from Pharmacy 
  where startdate >= '2024-11-01' AND enddate  < '2024-12-01'
) as s;
```

Result :

```
amtpaid_OPPatient   amtpaid_Pharmacy
100000              40000
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/ikhmNELC)